# Angular - how to make filter by case sensitive

Tags: angularjs

In my app, I am using the search box to filter the persons. the persons name are static(at present), how can i make this filter case sensitive?

because people can enter their name by their wish here. so I am looking this to filter by how the way they entered their name.

here is my config, but not working;

```
<div class="container">
        <h1>Directive Test 1</h1>
        <input type="search" name="search" ng-model="search" placeholder="Search a person" id="">
        <div class="list" ng-controller="List">
            <ul>
                <li ng-repeat="person in people | filter:search:upperCase"> // not working! {{person.name}}</li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Any one help me please?

**UPDATE**

my js code :

```
var List = function($scope){
    $scope.people = [
        {name:'Mo',age:20},
        {name:'Si', age:22},
        {name:'Yo', age:33}
    ]
}
```

[Demo is here(buggy)](http://jsfiddle.net/3gwebtrain/yyRLd/)

Comment: Is `upperCase` a model value in the current controller scope? If not, then use `| filter:search:true`.

Comment: but `filter:search:true` will only return whole name i.e. if You have John Jonnatan and Joanna and type "Jo", nothing will be filtered, you will have to type whole name 'Joanna'

Comment: true is not for uppercase, it expects full text entered to mach.

Comment: Yeah, that's true. But with the onboard filter it's simply not *doable* otherwise. If you want a case-sensitive partitial search, you'll have to write your one filter/comperator. @3gwebtrain So what is your question? Case-sensitive search or uppercase display?

Comment: case sensitive search.

Comment: Then write your own filter/comparator. See runTarms answer for that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could supply a comparator function to the filter like this:

```
<li ng-repeat="person in people | filter:search:comparatorFunction">
```

and in a controller:

```
$scope.comparatorFunction = function (name, search) {
    return (''+name).indexOf(''+search) > -1;
};
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: works. but not able to understand your function. can you explain me please?

Answer (score 0):

`uppercase` and `filter` are two different fitlers

change this

```
person in people | filter:search:upperCase
```

to this

```
person in people | filter:search | uppercase
```

`uppercase` filter is used when you want to render output html in uppercase

Now, to filter case-sensitive, use custom case sensitive filter

Updated fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/Tw7kW/

Comment: tied, no luck. if i type small 'm' still i am getting result as 'MO'

Comment: No, still it works like before. and I put true - it requires full phrase entered.