# Filter a case-sensitive data with duplicate entry in a column using search bar and return that particular row AngularJS

Tags: javascript, java, html, css, angularjs

My solution:
    
    
    
    
    AngularJS - Search Table - Filter 
    
    table, td  {
      border: 1px solid grey;
      border-collapse: collapse;
      padding: 5px;
    }

```
<body>
<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="namesCtrl"/> 
<p>Filtering input:</p>    
<p><input type="text" data-ng-model="search.City"></p>

<table>
  <tr data-ng-repeat="x in names | filter: search: strict ">
    <td> {{ x.Name }}</td>
    <td>{{ x.City }} </td>
    <td> {{ x.Country }}</td>

  </tr>
</table> 
<p>{{ City | lowercase }}</p>
<script>

var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
app.controller('namesCtrl', function($scope, $http) {
    $http.get("names.js")
    .success(function (response) {$scope.names = response.records;});
});
</script>
</body>
</html>

The above code displays the data from the table from the column "City". But I have a duplicate like,"Sao" and "sao". When the user searches for "Sao" the returned value should be the row of data which contains "Sao" as the city.
```

[Click here to view the solution before search](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9DdZU.jpg)

[Click here to view after the filter](https://i.stack.imgur.com/P3qPX.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at this answer provided is some other post.

https://stackoverflow.com/a/24798741/6654503

You can also update comparator function (if required) from the mentioned answer to incorporate your requirements.